# How can I set the block.bell.hit sound effect to a specific pitch?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

So, I am trying to use the block.bell.hit sound effect to make a set of tuned bells. I found a list of the /playsound pitches that are supposed to match each musical note, but the block.bell.hit sound effect seems to play more sharp, or more flat, at random. Is there a way to choose which sound file is played or just make the pitch more consistent?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the bell being hit have multiple audio files which are randomly selected, and I don't think you can change the pitch with a command.

You can however do this with note block sounds, so maybe use something like the note block bell sound.

syntax:
`/playsound block.note_block.<instrument> <track> <target> <coordinates> <volume> <pitch>`

you could use a command like this:
`/playsound block.note_block.bell record @p ~ ~ ~ 1 1`

note about the pitch value (the last value in this command):
"Specifies the pitch of the sound. Must be between 0.0 and 2.0 (inclusive), and values less than 0.5 are equivalent to 0.5. Values lower than 1.0 lower the pitch and increase the duration; values greater than 1.0 raise the pitch and reduce the duration. The pitch value is a multiplier applied to the frequency, so if a value between 0.5 and 1.0 (inclusive) is doubled, the pitch will be an octave higher.

In order for these to work, Position co-ordinates and volume need to be set." -mcstacker.net

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I was really hoping to use that one sound because it’s closest to a real bell sound. I did some more research, and you’re right. There doesn’t seem to be a way to select the audio files. I’ll try something else for now. Thanks again.

Comment: @MatthewMozingo you're welcome! In 1.20 minecraft is also adding the ability to play ambient mob sounds with mob heads above note blocks, and they made it so a player head could link to any sound. you should be able to use this for the bell sound which I think can be changed to any pitch using some sound editors, so it may be possible to do exactly what you want when minecraft 1.20 comes around. I don't think it works properly in the 1.20 datapack that mojang made but if it does work then you could also try it with that.